# Select first free datetime between two time in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, between, elapsedtime

I want find a best datetime that is before have a 20 minutes free time and also have at least 20 minutes in past.
So

in database:

1. 2014-03-24 10:30
2. 2014-03-24 11:10
3. 2014-03-24 12:00
4. 2014-03-24 12:30

If i run at 11:15 i want to get 2014-03-24 11:30 because 11-30-11:10 = 20 and 12:00-11:30 >= 20.

So, i need select a datetime not a row in database (and insert it later). I need to find the nearest date that is have a 20-20 minutes blank period before and after in the database. Otherwise, i'm looking for it the 40 minutes hole in the database and get the middle.

This is possible to solve in a mysql query?
thanks :)

Comment: I don't follow the full explanation.  What does it mean "20 minutes free time"?

Comment: I really have no idea what you're asking.  Can you rephrase the question a bit more carefully?

Answer (score 1):

To get the most recent time stamp in the past that is more than 20 minutes ago:

```
select *
from table t
where datetimefield < now() - interval 20 minutes
order by datetimefield desc
limit 1;
```

If you only want to limit the ones where there is no timestamp for 20 minutes after:

```
select *
from table t
where datetimefield < now() - interval 20 minutes and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.datetimefield between t.datetimefield and t.datetimefield + interval 20 minutes
                )
order by datetimefield desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. So, i need select a datetime not a row in database (and insert it later). I need to find the nearest date that is have a 20-20 minutes blank period before and after in the database. Otherwise, i'm looking for it the 40 minutes hole in the database and get the middle.